# How to implement summernote using jquery

Tags: summernote

**Steps-in-Detail**

1. Where to Declare the pluggin.
2. How to customize the options.
3. Working Examples.

> This is the concept which can replace a regular text-area

Answer (score 0):

1. Please refer to Summernote api for customization.
2. Changes made in js pluggin will reflect the changes in UI.
3. We can Create Many things under one roof.

---

[MarkitDown Api](https://markdown-it.github.io/)

---

[summernote api](https://github.com/summernote/summernote)

Answer (score 0):

There are other replacements too, try to use markitdown editor, which gives to variegated themes and custom styles.

Comment: These Questions are not silly depending on the requirement in your project, these things boost up your production.